# Unable to run scala specs2 tests parallely from sbt prompt

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

below are my classes.

```
class Spec1 {
  def is = {
    function1 ^
    function2 ^
    function3 ^
    end
  }
 def function1 = {
  println("Spec1")
 }
 def function2 = {
   Thread.sleep(120000)
   println("sleeping-Spec1")
 }
 def function3 = {
   println("Spec1")
 }
}


class Spec2 {
  def is = {
    function1 ^
    function2 ^
    function3 ^
    end
   }
 def function1 = {
   println("Spec2")
  }
 def function2 = {
   println("Spec2")
  }
 def function3 = {
   println("Spec2")
  }
}


class MasterSpec {
  def is = {
   Step(setup) ^ new Spec1 ^ new Spec2 ^ Step(teardown)
  }
  def setup = {
   setup code 
  }
  def teardown = {
   teardown code
  }
}
```

From sbt prompt i run `test-only MasterSpec`

Expected output :-
the print statements will be printed in random. Because by default sbt runs specs in parallel. The output should look some thing like this.

```
Spec2
Spec1
Spec1
Spec2
sleeping-Spec1
Spec2
```

Actual output :-
the print statements are in order.

```
Spec1
sleeping-Spec1
Spec1
Spec2
Spec2
Spec2`
```

When i copied setup and teardown methods from MasterSpec in individual specs and ran `test-only Spec1 Spec2`, i was able to run them parallely. Why does `test-only MasterSpec` do not run tests in parallel? Is there a way i could run those specs parallely from MasterSpec?

Answer (score 1):

The parallelism of examples execution indeed stops at the Specification boundary. One thing you can do is to `inline` the contents of `Spec1` and `Spec2`:

```
class MasterSpec {
  def is = 
    Step(setup) ^ 
      inline(new Spec1) ^ 
      inline(new Spec2) ^ 
    Step(teardown)

  def setup = "setup code".pp 
  def teardown = "teardown code".pp
}
```

The display will be a bit different though. In particular you won't see spec start/spec end and statistics for each spec, but all the examples will be executed in parallel.